How to avoid duplicate code when I impl a trait for many structs in rust?
I have one trait A which contains many methods, at the same time I have a lot of structs which need to impl it , but I really don't wanna impl A one by one for structs ,because it has so many methods and there are lots of duplicate code, it looks terrible! My solution is that I just impl A for BaseA. BaseA implements all of methods in trait A, and struct-B、struct-C、struct-D......just implement some of the methods for trait A as needed, and leave the rest to BaseA to do!
The code example is as follows
trait A {
    fn method1(&self);
    fn method2(&self);
    // untill method100(&self)!!! 
}
struct BaseA {}
impl A for BaseA {
    fn method1(&self) {
        println!("i am BaseA 1");
    }

    fn method2(&self) {
        println!("i am BaseA 2");
    }
    // untill method100(&self)!!! 
}
struct B {
    base: BaseA,
}

struct C {
    base: BaseA,
}

struct D {
    base: BaseA,
}


impl A for C {
    fn method1(&self) {
        println!("i am C 1");
    }

    fn method2(&self) {
        self.baseA.method2();
    }
    // untill method100(&self)!!!
}

This solution is implemented by delegating to BaseA to avoid a lot of duplicate code, but it is terrible either! I still need to implement method1 to method100 for all of my structs!
Actually I used to code with Java, Java can solve this problem through Inheritance mechanism, so what is better solution for my problem in rust???

rust-analyzer has a "Generate delegate" assist if you only care about writing, or you can use a macro.

Not only for writing code, but each structure has to implement so many methods, it's difficult to maintain and  it seem not necessary

In addition to the idea presented in the answer, there is also a crate that automates (to an extent) the code you'd write manually.

One way to do it is to have all your child structs implement AsRef<BaseA> and to add default implementations in the trait definition that delegate to BaseA:
trait A: AsRef<BaseA> {
   fn method1 (&self) {
      self.as_ref().method1();
   }
   fn method2 (&self) {
      self.as_ref().method1();
   }
}

struct BaseA {}
impl AsRef<BaseA> for BaseA {
   fn as_ref (&self) -> &BaseA {
      &self
   }
}
impl A for BaseA {
   fn method1 (&self) {
      println!("BaseA::method1");
   }
   fn method2 (&self) {
      println!("BaseA::method2");
   }
}

struct B {
   base: BaseA,
}
impl AsRef<BaseA> for B {
   fn as_ref (&self) -> &BaseA {
      &self.base
   }
}
impl A for B {
   fn method1 (&self) {
      println!("B::method1");
   }
   // No `method2` -> use the one from `BaseA`
}

fn main() {
   let v = B { base: BaseA{} };
   v.method1();
   v.method2();
}

Playground
That being said, Rust is not an OO language and trying to force OO patterns in Rust will be painful in the long run. You should instead try to rethink your architecture in Rust terms.

I got it, all methods in the trait are implemented by passing get_ref to the BaseA.

It is indeed painful to be object-oriented in Rust, but currently I am refactoring a system based on object-oriented language design using Rust

It is really useful ! This way, all the costs are transferred to the trait. Although BaseA implements trait A, which in turn is of type AsRef, the degree of coupling is not high
